# Twitter API JSON Help

Tags: php, json, twitter

I've been trying to play with the Twitter API a bit and this is what I have so far:

```
function get_twitter_user_data($user_id, $limit = 3)
    {           
        $twitter_username = 'twitter';

        $twitter_json = @file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?&include_rts=1&screen_name='.$twitter_username.'&count='.$limit);
        $twitter_data = json_decode($twitter_json);

        if ( ! $twitter_data) {
            return array();
        }

        foreach ($twitter_data[0]->user as $user) {
            $image = $user->profile_image_url;
        }

        // doesn't do anything
        echo $image.'<br/><br/>';

        // works
        echo $twitter_data[0]->user->profile_image_url;
    }
```

Been trying to figure this out far too long. And yes, I've done research but the solutions that I've found have no worked for me. I think maybe I'm just extremely tired and can't see the issue right now.

Anybody mind explaining why looping through `$twitter_data` doesn't work but output a direct value with `$twitter_data[0]->user->profile_image_url` does?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this instead:

```
foreach ($twitter_data as $status) {
    $user = $status->user;
```

`foreach ($twitter_data[0]->user as $user)` iterates over the values of the poster of the first status.

Comment: Oh, I see now what I was doing wrong. So you loop through the array of objects then save the user object to a variable that you can later on use - for instance, if you return $user from that function, you can then somewhere else call $user->profile_image_url. Many thanks arnaud :)